# Python - How to publish messages(Json Data) to a topic?

Tags: json, api, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe

what I am aiming to do is to take the data I pulled from an Restful api call   publish it to a topic I created  specifically have the messages show every key and value.

```
# PubSub Vars
    project_id = os.environ.get('PROJECT_ID')
    topic_name = os.environ.get('TOPIC_NAME')
    c_tenant         = os.environ['c_tenant']
    tpsswd           = os.environ['tpsswd']
    c_user           = os.environ['c_user']
    tenant_id        = os.environ['tenant_id']
    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
    topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)


def get_callback(f, data):
    def callback(f):
        try:
            print(f.result())
            futures.pop(data)
        except:  # noqa
            print('Please handle {} for {}.'.format(f.exception(), data))

    return callback

verify = True
    url = 'https://%s/Redrock/query' % c_tenant
    headers = {
        'X-NATIVE-CLIENT': 'true',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % bearer_token
        }

    r = requests.get(url, json={"script": "@/lib/server_user_activity.js"}, headers=headers, verify = verify)
response = json.loads(r)
traffic = json.dumps(response)
    if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        for item in traffic.items:
            Jsonresponse = publisher.publish(topic_path,data =)
            print(key + ':' + value)
```

[Here is the documentation I am following](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher)  from Google but I do not fully understand it as I am not seeing any data published to my topic. Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Comment: - Does your Topic has at least one subscription? (You need to have a subscription, otherwise the message will be discarded). Can you print out the Jsonresponse and see if you get an error back?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you don't understand?  To publish from Python, as per your link, you called publisher.publish() with the parameters identifying the topic and the data.  I'm always a fan of crawl, walk, run.  See if you can't write a sample app that merely publishes a fixed content string and validate that works for you.

Comment: The code that you posted has missing parts such as ` Jsonresponse = publisher.publish(topic_path,data =)` that gives SyntaxError and other IndentationError. Please edit it so we can understand the issue.